# jOOQ - rollbacks after selects

Tags: jooq

I have a problem which depends on that there are a lot of rollbacks after selects in database statements generated by jOOQ library i.e. 2000 requests generated 300k rollbacks (diagnostic data from APM tool - Dynatrace). I suspect that it causes CPU saturation on database virtual machine. I also don't have an idea what is the reason of occurence of rollbacks after selects. I use Spring Boot 2.7.12 with jOOQ 3.16.11 and PostgreSQL 15 database.

Comment: jOOQ doesn't auto-generate such rollbacks. But why not use Dynatrace to drill down to the cause from the statistic? It's perfect for this type of analysis job.